# File_put_contents(./composer.lock): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, composer-php, ubuntu-20.04

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I'm trying to get my Ubuntu web server running, but I have a problem with composer. When I run `composer install` it outputs this error `[ErrorException] file_put_contents(./composer.lock): Failed to open stream: Permission denied`.
I found a solution for this on the internet, but it doesn't work for me

Not working solution:

```
 sudo chown -R $USER ~/.composer/
```

It outputs

```
chown: cannot access '/home/admin/.composer/': No such file or directory
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. Does anyone know what should I do?

Comment: `~/.composer/`  is not `./composer.lock`, despite the diagnostic message that `~/.composer/` is not a file or directory, the operand itself already looks wrong in the `chown(1)` invocation. Composer only tells you with which file it failed, but you have to find out first why the permission is denied. Then change the permissions to your benefit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue can easily be solved by creating the lock file and then modifying the ownership.

1. `sudo touch composer.lock`
2. `sudo chown -R $USER ./composer.lock`
3. `composer update`

OR

Just own the projec folder:

`sudo chown -R $USER path/to/project/folder`

With this, you don't have to use `sudo` to run `composer update`

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was simply to cd to /fullpath-to-my-project and then run the composer command.

Composer documentation is so poor that I had no idea that you have to be in the root directory of the site before using it. This may be obvious to most people, but not necessarily to newbies.

This solution, of course, implies the correct permissions as fixed by the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.composer/` won't work because indeed there's no file/folder in the Laravel structure called 'composer' but rather 'composer.lock'.
Instead, running `sudo chown $USER composer.lock` would make more sense (replace $USER with your actual username).
This however won't fix the issue entirely.

That said, you should do the following to ensure that `composer install` (or `composer update`) runs successfully: I am assuming your project path is /var/www/html/your-project.

1. Change ownership of your Laravel project folder:
   `sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/html/your-project`
2. Change the permissions of your Laravel project folder: `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/your-project`
3. Make the storage folder writable: `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/your-project/storage`
4. Then make sure you add the current user to the www-data group: `sudo usermod $USER -g www-data` (replace $USER with your username)

Now you should be able to run `composer install` or `composer update` without permission errors.